# Storing tags along with stream data to a file in gnuradio

Tags: zeromq, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I am trying to store tags along with the stream data to a file in gnuradio. While zeroMQ blocks can be used to transfer the stream data along with the tags to a socket, I am unable to use it to store the tags to a file.

Is there another way to serialize the stream along with the tags ? or another block I can use to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to store tags along with the stream data to a file in gnuradio

Use the metadata file sink.

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what I needed.